# Chocolatey and nodejs package

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

I've installed NodeJS with Chocolatey (choco install nodejs.install). Chocolatey is on my path in Windows, and command `node -v` worked.

But, if i install Grunt or Bower, Windows don't found Bower/Grunt command.

Do you have any idea why i can't use Bower or Grunt?

Comment: Did you use NPM to install Bower?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/649
This helped me. The December 28th 2014 comment and January 1st comment. I didn't need to fix the PATH since I restarted cmd after installation.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you because I had the same issue.

My Chocolatey install path for those tools are in this folder:

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline.0.12.0\tools\

So add that path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: My nodejs is the 0.12 version as my path tells, so check yours at the ProgramData Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this as well using Chocolatey.  To get grunt and bower to work from anywhere, you have to install it globally, i.e:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

Hopefully this will help you.